# Angular 8 - Empty route navigates to incorrect component

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular 2 application set up with the **app.routing.ts** file looking like so:

```
     // User Pages
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

    // Client Pages
    { path: 'clients', loadChildren: () => import('./clients/clients.module').then(mod => mod.ClientModule) },

    // Auth pages
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'register/:token', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'forgottenPassword', component: ForgottenPasswordComponent },
    { path: 'forgottenPassword/:token', component: ForgottenPasswordComponent },

    // Error pages
    { path: 'forbidden', component: ForbiddenComponent },
    { path: 'maintenance', component: MaintenanceComponent },

    // otherwise redirect to 404
    { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
```

Now for some reason, everything works as expected, *except* from the base route. When I visit http://localhost:4200, it redirects to http://localhost:4200/login. Whilst I do have code that redirects the user to the login page if they're not logged in, i've verified that this is not being called.

Router Tracing Shows the following when I attempt to navigate to the root of the application:

```
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart(id: 6, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart {id: 6, url: "/", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized(id: 6, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized {id: 6, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart(id: 6, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart {id: 6, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: NavigationCancel
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationCancel(id: 6, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationCancel {id: 6, url: "/", reason: "Navigation ID 6 is not equal to the current navigation id 7"}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart(id: 7, url: '/login')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart {id: 7, url: "/login", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized(id: 7, url: '/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') } )
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized {id: 7, url: "/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/login", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart(id: 7, url: '/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') } )
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart {id: 7, url: "/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/login", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart(path: 'login')
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 7, url: '/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') } , shouldActivate: true)
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 7, url: "/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/login", state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ResolveStart
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveStart(id: 7, url: '/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') } )
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveStart {id: 7, url: "/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/login", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ResolveEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveEnd(id: 7, url: '/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') } )
platform-browser.js:292 ResolveEnd {id: 7, url: "/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/login", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: NavigationCancel
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationCancel(id: 7, url: '/login')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationCancel {id: 7, url: "/login", reason: "Navigation ID 7 is not equal to the current navigation id 8"}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart(id: 8, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationStart {id: 8, url: "/", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationEnd(path: 'login')
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized(id: 8, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
platform-browser.js:292 RoutesRecognized {id: 8, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart(id: 8, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'') } )
platform-browser.js:292 GuardsCheckStart {id: 8, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:292 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:301 Router Event: NavigationCancel
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationCancel(id: 8, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:292 NavigationCancel {id: 8, url: "/", reason: "Navigation ID 8 is not equal to the current navigation id 9"}
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Visiting http://localhost:4201/dashboard works as expected. Visiting http://localhost:4201 does not, I get redirected to http://localhost:4201/login

EDIT: **auth.guard.ts** as requested:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) {  }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your auth guard code?

Comment: @FarooqAhmedKhan, this has been added to the original post, though I've hacked it by adding "return true" to the Guard and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that within my modular routing, there was a particular route that had been configured wrong, and as a result the router was matching that particular route instead of the one I was expecting. Fixing this route configuration resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is AuthGuard problem. http://localhost:4200 redirect you in http://localhost:4200/dashboard and AuthGuard redirect to login

Comment: It is not an auth guard problem. I am able to navigate throughout the app, where AuthGuard protects  pretty much all routes. I've also just added a "return true" into the AuthGuard so it always allows access, and the problem persists.